# How do I put $1 into an array with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Basically I'm trying to parse my template with preg_replace by finding anything that looks like `{$variable}` on the HTML file.

```
public function parse_file($file) {

    return preg_replace('/{\$(.+?)}/i', "$this->params[$1]", $this->get_file($file));

}
```

However, this is returning `Array(variable)`, instead of whatever `variable` is set to in the `$this->params` array.

I'd like it to return `$this->params['variable']`.

To clarify, this is what my HTML file looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$variable}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://codepad.org/qYd8DB6C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead, eg (PHP 5.3)

```
// using $this in an anonymous function is not very well defined
$params = $this->params;

return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function (array $matches) use ($params) {
    return $params[$matches[1]];
}, $this->get_file($file));
```